# Passing other information along with SIGTERM

Tags: linux, unix, signals, sudo

I have many Unix processes running as different users in my system.

I have provided a way to monitor these processes from the web application. The web application also allows users to take action on these processes (like sending SIGTERM) from the UI.

The design is as follows - when the user clicks on the kill button for the process that he thinks should no longer be running, UI sends a request to the server to kill the corresponding process. The server is running as a god user (not root) which has permissions to sudo as run user of the process. Server sudos as the run user of the process and sends SIGTERM to the process. This way process gets killed by kill action from UI.

Now my requirement is, I want to log the user (browser user) who actually took action from the UI in the process log. But since I sudo'ed as the run user of the process I am not sure how can I pass browser user information to the process while sending SIGTERM.

Unix experts?

Comment: It's not possible to send any information along with a signal. You should use some other interprocess communication mechanism, such as sockets or message queues.

Comment: What Barnar said:  from your description it's quite unclear how you go about the logging.  Do you expect the terminating process to log who killed it?  That would be an odd design choice; why not have that logged from the process that actually triggers the "sudo" and does the killing?

Comment: @tink since there are zillions of such processes running on a daily basis and since these individual processes already have their respective log files where they keep a log of what is happening within a process hence I think it is reasonably a good design to log in process log file itself and this logging should happen as part of signal handling function of the terminating process itself.

Comment: @nate it's SIGTERM not SIGKILL, I have updated the question.

Comment: If you look at `man sigaction`, you can see the `siginfo_t` which shows all the information provided to a signal handler.  The closest thing to what you want is `si_uid` which is the real uid of the process sending the signal; but `sudo` sets both its real and effective user id, so those will both be the process's own uid.  But there's no way to send arbitrary data along with a signal: as Barmar says, you need a different form of IPC.